# iGoogle-like interface with PHP

Tags: php

I want to create a website that offers users modules/widgets that can be dragged around, closed, minimized... like iGoogle (not necessarily looking like that, it's just an example). These modules/widgets should have the ability to dynamically load the contents from DB and show them. What tool/resource you suggest to do this as fast as possible. I know programming but I'm new to web and PHP and I'm supposed to deliver this project in 20 days tops! So I prefer the minimum amount of learning if possible.

Comment: This is not constructive at all, you're asking us to build an entire site for you.

Comment: You will need about 50.000$... that's it.

Comment: @Cyclone: I'm not asking you to build anything. I'm just looking for a resource to get information to help me do what I need.

Comment: @webarto: I don't get what you're talking about!!!!

Comment: @Alireza Noori, I'm saying, you can't make something just like that in 20 days, even if you work 24hrs a day with knowledge on how to do it.

Comment: Well, the backend is pretty much done and the deadline is to get it done to some leven not to finish it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/) a tutorial from nettuts that teaches just what you're asking for (except the loading from DB part). The live demo is [here](https://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/127_iNETTUTS/demo/index.html)

Comment: I've tried the demo but it doesn't allow me to drag/move it around nor does it allow me to close it.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori What browser are you using ? It works for me under Firefox, chrome and IE (The drag and drop doesn't work under IE9 though)

Comment: I'm using IE9. Well it's a problem. The website should work in any browser like iGoogle.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of project you will require client side scripting i.e. Javascript (PHP is server side scripting)

JQuery makes writing Javascript considerably less tedious and JQuery UI allows you to add interactions to DOM objects such as: Draggable, Droppable, Resizable, Selectable, Sortable which will make creating the widgets much easier. 
http://jqueryui.com/

You might not need to write the windowing yourself the Elgg social network PHP framework has a theme called the Deyan Shell which pretty much does what you need out of the box:
http://community.elgg.org/pg/plugins/project/752334/developer/vabel/deyan-shell

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily PHP, what you're referring to is client side. Take a look at jQuery, that allows the minimize/maximize, drag/drop, etc.

There is also other JavaScript libraries out there like MooTools and Prototype.

Comment: Yes, you're right. My bad. But where can I learn these stuff?